# Replace certain last words typed with html in contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, range, selection, wysihtml5

I'm trying to replace certain keywords in a content-editable div with hyper-links on the fly as the user is typing.  I have it working great with the first word they type by first splitting the entire string by " ", then grabbing the most recent word and if it's one of my keywords, I find the start index and end index in the entire string then do:

```
range.setStart(myDiv.firstChild, startOfWordIndex);
range.setEnd(myDiv.firstChild, endOfWordIndex);
range.deleteContents();
range.insertNode(...);
```

where the node I'm inserting is a hyper-link I've created but didn't type it all out here for brevity's sake.

My problem is, after that node is inserted, I can no longer use the myDiv.firstChild in my setStart() method because I new have new nodes in front of where the user is typing.

This is my first crack at content-editable html so I'm not sure how to grab the last node nor am I sure that using the start and end indices of my word would work there anyway since those are based on the entire length of the div contents.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some sleep, I got this sorted out on my own:  Heavily commented in case in can help someone else.

```
function replaceLastWordWithLink(editContent) {
    var selection, selectedRange, range, node, frag, el, selectionText, wordStart, wordEnd, currentWord;
    // set the selection
    selection = window.getSelection();
    // set the range by the cursor
    selectedRange = selection.getRangeAt(0);
    // set the "global" range
    range = document.createRange();
    // get all node contents of global range
    range.selectNodeContents(editContent);
    // get the node the cursor is in
    node = selectedRange.startContainer;
    // point the global range to node the cusor is in and start of 0
    range.setStart(node, 0);
    // point the global range to node the cursor is in and end of where cursor is
    range.setEnd(node, selectedRange.startOffset);
    // create the fragment for the contents
    frag = range.cloneContents();
    // create a pseudo element to place the fragment in
    el = document.createElement("span");
    // place fragment in pseudo element
    el.appendChild(frag);
    // get the text from the pseduo element
    selectionText = el.innerText;
    // pattern to see if there are spaces
    spacePattern = /\s/;
    if (!spacePattern.test(selectionText)) {
        // no spaces so the start of the word index is at 0
        wordStart = 0;
        // no spaces so end of the word index is just where the cusor is (the total length of the text)
        wordEnd = selectionText.length;
    } else {
        // split off the last word in the text
        currentWord = selectionText.split(/\s/).reverse()[0].toLowerCase();
        // get the start of the word's index in the string
        wordStart = selectionText.lastIndexOf(currentWord);
        // get the end of the word's index by adding start of word index to the word length
        wordEnd = wordStart + currentWord.length;
    }
    // now set the range to the current word
    range.setStart(node, wordStart);
    range.setEnd(node, wordEnd);
    // now remove the current word
    range.deleteContents();
    // now replace the word with the link
    var el = document.createElement("a");
    el.href = "http://www.yahoo.com";
    el.text = selectedText;
    range.insertNode(el);
}
```